# How to use Mathquill on my website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mathquill

I'm having problems in using mathquill on my website. 
I'm new to this.
I'm stuck in this part

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/mathquill.css">`
  <script src="/path/to/mathquill.min.js"></script>
```

I dont know what to put on the hrefs because I'm not seeing those files from mathquill file i got from github..

i downloaded the latest mathquill files and its inside htdocs(xampp) or www(wamp) together with my index.php.

Do i have to place my index.php inside mqthquill-0.10.1 folder?

Here is my

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/mathquill.css"/>
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/path/to/mathquill.js"></script>
```

I appreciate if someone could give me the steps on how to use mathquill.
thanks in advance

Comment: I just downloaded the .zip off Github via the "latest release" link in [the docs](http://docs.mathquill.com/en/latest/Getting_Started/) and there's a `mathquill.js` and `mathquill.css` file right there in it.

Comment: i already downloaded the file but i don't know  how to use it in.. like the codes. and calling it. i copied and pasted it on my site but its not working. i think theres something im not doing..

Comment: The docs have an entire section on "getting started". Read it and follow along.

Comment: dude what i want to know is i dont know what to put on the href. do i need to leave it as is or do i need to change it. im new to this thing. im not that knowledgeable in programming

Answer (score 3):

### Option 1

You can either download the mathquill.css and mathquill.js files from github and use them from your directory.

If you have your folder (directory) structure as below:

```
appFolder
.. scripts
.... mathquill.js
.... index.js
.. css
.... mathquill.css
 myPage.html
```

Here's how you would reference the CSS and JS files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/mathquill.css">`
<script src="/scripts/mathquill.min.js"></script>
```

An easy way to check if your paths are correct is to put the entire URL in the browser's address bar. For example, if you are browsing the page as:

```
www.mydomain.com/mypage.html
```

The links to css and js files in the example folder structure I mentioned above would be:

```
www.mydomain.com/scripts/mathquill.js
www.mydomain.com/css/mathquill.css
```

### Option 2

You could use the CDN to get the JS and CSS files on your page. Just copy the below two lines on to your html page, and you are ready to go.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathquill/0.10.1/mathquill.min.css">`
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathquill/0.10.1/mathquill.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification dude...
but my problem is i cant see the mathquill.js and mathquill.css in the file i downloaded from github.. the "mathquill-0.10.1.tgz"

Comment: You might want to unzip it. Use 7zip or something to get the files from it.

Comment: maybe there's something that i ddnt understand from the doc in mathquill.com. im not good in english...

Comment: That's alright, I am posting the CDN links. Hopefully they will simplify this for you.

Comment: Yeah... im done extracting the files. ...and already placed it together with my index.php

Im seeing intro.js and others. i cant see the mathquill.js and mathquill.css

Comment: Dude thanks a lot,. i saw the mathquill js and css on the 
"mathquill-0.10.1.tgz" not on mathquill-0.10.1.zip file

thanks for your great help

Comment: dude.. do i need to put the .MathField inside the script and not inside a function? 
it seems that if i try to place it inside a function. its not working

Comment: Yes, MathField is a function, so that  goes in the javascript. But putting it inside a function should not be a problem.You  should check out the MathQuill documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- COPY AND PAST THIS CODE HTML IN SOME EDITOR FOR BETTER VISUALIZATION, AFTER RUN-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Run  Mathquill</title>


        <!-- YOU NEED  mathquill.css , jquery and mathquill.js SEARCH AND PICK IT SOMEWHERE, SEARCH ON THE WEB IF THIS DOWN  NOT RUN-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathquill/0.10.1/mathquill.css"/> 
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathquill/0.10.1/mathquill.js"></script>

        <!-- INFORM  THE LATEST AVERSION INTERFACE WITH THIS CODE   -->
        <script>
            var MQ = MathQuill.getInterface(2);
        </script>


    </head>

    <body>

          <!--EXAMPLE COMMON TEXT TRANSFORMED WITH MATHQUILL  -->
         <p>Solve <span id="problem">f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c + = 0</span>.</p>
            <script>
                  var problemSpan = document.getElementById('problem');
                 MQ.StaticMath(problemSpan);
            </script> 




        <!-- EXAMPLE TO  CREATE AN EDITABLE MATH FIELD  -->
        <p><span id="answer">x=</span></p>
        <script>
            var answerSpan = document.getElementById('answer');
            var answerMathField = MQ.MathField(answerSpan, {
                handlers: {
                edit: function() {
                    var enteredMath = answerMathField.latex(); // Get entered math in LaTeX format
                    checkAnswer(enteredMath);
                }
                }
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation ?

Comment: I tried to explain with comments, they are written between <! - -> the sample codes are from the Mathquill website.

But in short you need the files "scr"  in <head> and some code of use in <body>.

I was unable to run with the github files. Only with CDN link that I found on the web.

I am also learning how to use it. :)

good?

Comment: `checkAnswer(enteredMath);`  what does this do in this